# One function for multiple elements in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Assuming we have this bellow markup (already generated, so I can't use `ng-repeat` to display it).

```
<svg>
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
    ...
    <!-- more than 100 times -->
</svg>
```

What would be an alternative for this jQuery code

```
$('path').click(function(){
    console.log('ok');
});
```

in AngularJS without having to repeat `ng-click` n-times?

Comment: I think, you will need to bind the ng-click with 'path' and for doing this you can use this as an alternative **$('path').attr('data-ng-click', 'some_function_to_be_called()');**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a path directive:

```
app.directive('path', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('click', function() {
                 console.log('ok');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

`ngRepeat` will create a child scope for each iteration, so to preserve this scope, the directive is setup to create a child scope (`scope: true`, in the directive definition). That way, each path element will have its own child scope that prototypically inherits from parent scope and will not interfere with its siblings.

If you also plan on triggering a digest cycle to update the views (which is what `ngClick` does automatically), you need to wrap your code with an $apply block inside of the click  handler.

```
link: function(scope, element) {
    element.on('click', function() {
         scope.$apply(function() {
             console.log('ok');
             scope.model = 'hello world'; // update the model, then trigger a digest.
         });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `directive` that will do the logging or whatever you really want to:

```
<svg>
    <path log-element></path>
    ...
    <!-- more than 100 times -->
</svg>
```

Or:

```
<svg log-inner-elements>
    <path></path>
    ...
    <!-- more than 100 times -->
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), you can do some jquery functionalities.

HOWEVER..

When doing DOM manipulations in angular, it is recommended to use directives (`ng-click`, or [create your own](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)), so as to maintain separation of concerns which is the angular way.